# Google map 2 does not appear on activity in android 4.x

Tags: android

I added google play service v 2 to my project and following code working on android 2.3 , but on the android 4 map does not appearing on the activity
I'm new in android, Here is my codes

```
public class MapActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        generateUI();
        MapFragment map = new MapFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.first_fragment, map);
        transaction.commit();


    }


}
```

And layout  :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.realtyna.android.activity.MapActivity" >

   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/second_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No wonder you cannot see it as you explicitly set it so in your layout:

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```